# How to draw Balanced yAix in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I`m trying to draw new multi line chart in Highcharts. How do I draw Balanced yAxis?

I try setting tickPositions, tickInterval etc... use tickPositions this:

[image: Image with tickPositions]

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {

    },
    yAxis:{
        tickPositions: [0, 100, 1000, 10000],
        //tickInterval : 1000

    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Installation',
            data: [4100, 4009]
        }, {
            name: 'Manufacturing',
            data: [1100, 1009]
        }, {
            name: 'Sales & Distribution',
            data: [110, 1009]
        },{
            name: 'E4',
            data: [50, 1009]
        }]
});
```

Something like this:

[image: Image with evenly spaced y-axis]

Comment: What is a balanced yaxis?

Comment: Um.. I am not good at English,  first [enter image description here] is that I try to drawing Highcharts, second [enter image description here] is that I want to draw like this. so  I want to uniformly adjust the y-axis spacing.

Comment: how do i hold the y-axis( 1~100, 100~1000, 1000~10000)  gap evenly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code uses a `yAxis` with `type: 'linear'`. Your example result image uses a `yAxis` with `type: 'logarithmic'`.

You can change your code to ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/y39kwL0j/)):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {

    },
    yAxis:{
        type: 'logarithmic',
        tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Installation',
            data: [4100, 4009]
        }, {
            name: 'Manufacturing',
            data: [1100, 1009]
        }, {
            name: 'Sales & Distribution',
            data: [110, 1009]
        },{
            name: 'E4',
            data: [50, 1009]
        }]
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I change the E4 data  like this : [0.06324, 0.12724]. as a result, the chart  show differently y-axis gap(range) [E4 example](https://jsfiddle.net/sako1912/b3dw6amn/). how do i drawing  y-axis(1~100, 100~1000, 1000~10000).

Comment: @sako I updated the answer. You can use `tickPositions`, as shown in the example.  Each value X in `tickPositions` equals `10^X`. Also, [here's an update of your E4 example](https://jsfiddle.net/2d1m9xvy/).

Comment: (Note that if you want it to be truly equal, regardless of the actual numeric values (and not actually using a logarithmic scale) then you'll probably have to use a `category` axis, and "cheat" on both your series data and your label formatting.)

Comment: really thank you for help me. I can finish drawing in HighCharts. [finish JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sako1912/59r78q6j/50/)